# Why jquery can't parse /#{ inside array string?

Tags: jquery, json

I have array attached to data-categories attribute of an html element like following:

```
data-categories='["Commit Sha: 2ee57d5&lt;br&gt;Commit Date: 2017-05-21 14:29:00 UTC&lt;br&gt;Commit Message: remove verify option\n\ngit-s...&lt;br&gt;ruby 2.5.0dev (2017-05-21 trunk 58832) [x86_64-linux]", "Commit Sha: 48070ce&lt;br&gt;Commit Date: 2017-05-21 16:45:35 UTC&lt;br&gt;Commit Message: downloader cache\n\n* tool/do...&lt;br&gt;ruby 2.5.0dev (2017-05-21 trunk 58833) [x86_64-linux]", "Commit Sha: 47f2bd9&lt;br&gt;Commit Date: 2017-05-21 19:25:19 UTC&lt;br&gt;Commit Message: Use should_receive expectat...&lt;br&gt;ruby 2.5.0dev (2017-05-22 trunk 58835) [x86_64-linux]", "Commit Sha: 913afdf&lt;br&gt;Commit Date: 2017-05-21 19:27:08 UTC&lt;br&gt;Commit Message: test_string.rb,test_symbol....&lt;br&gt;ruby 2.5.0dev (2017-05-22 trunk 58836) [x86_64-linux]", "Commit Sha: 40bc846&lt;br&gt;Commit Date: 2017-05-21 19:28:48 UTC&lt;br&gt;Commit Message: string.c: fix String\#{casec...&lt;br&gt;ruby 2.5.0dev (2017-05-22 trunk 58837) [x86_64-linux]"]'
```

Although this array seems valid json, when I call `$('.element').data('categories')` it returns me non parsed string. And when I call `JSON.parse($('.element').data('categories'))` I get parse error with Unrecognized `#`.

I guess something is wrong with having `\#{` in string but can't figure out what.

Is this maybe a bug?

Thanks

Comment: It's almost impossible to see anything (I presume it's HTML). You should print the output of `$('.element').data('categories')` into the console and maybe post such output into a JSON validator.

Comment: use  \\   fix  String\\# rather then \#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) you have an unescaped backslash:

```
"String\#{cas"
```

... should be:

```
"String\\#{cas"
```

[JSON](http://json.org/) is not JavaScript and will not ignore invalid escape sequences. The only valid ones are these:

[image: Escape sequences]

The overall issue may be a symptom of JSON being generated by string concatenation, rather than using a proper library.